# Nuxt SSR with Firebase Integration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I tried to restructure the project folder so that it can be deployed to Firebase, take a look to this repository [Nuxt Firebase Vuetify](https://github.com/jefrydco/nuxt-firebase-vuetify). On `nuxt.config.js` I changed the buildDir to `../functions/.nuxt`, at first sight it looks worked. But whenever I use custom component from UI framework like Vuetify, it becomes error. On the browser console, there is an error like this

> The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching
>   server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML
>   markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or
>   missing . Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.

Any idea how can I solve this? Or maybe I missed any other configuration on that project?

Comment: Maybe you may move your `src` folder to functions folder and set `buildDir` as .nuxt instead  ../functions/.nuxt. Then in the Cloud Function set your `buildDir` as `src/.nuxt`

Comment: Maybe this video help for you https://youtu.be/ZYUWsjUxxUQ

Answer (score 3):

So this is quite old, but I happened to stumble across the same issue just a few days ago, so maybe this can help you or someone else in the future.

To my understanding, this issue is caused due to the `vue` module, which is a dependency of Nuxt, being installed inside the functions folder. When you run Nuxt with the `buildDir` set to `functions/.nuxt` and `import Vue from 'vue'` in your plugins, you get another Vue-class than the one being used by Nuxt. This is a bug in Nuxt, as far as I know.

**How to hotfix this:**

- Remove the `nuxt` and `vue` modules from your `node_modules` inside the `functions` directory, all will run regardless.
- You will need to reinstall the modules before deploying to Firebase, if you use any of these modules in your Firebase Functions.

Comment: Is it also caused by minimum node version of Firebase, currently Firebase has node version 6.x.x but the minimum requirement of Nuxt is 8.x.x?

Comment: That is a whole other issue, but if the global components aren’t working locally either, the problem is probably not related to Node version.

Answer (score 1):

Metaphalo's answer works for me, to this I wanted to add that if you have a srcDir: 'src' in which all the nuxt directories are, I recommend adding.

nuxt.config

`srcDir: 'src',
buildDir: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'functions/.nuxt' : '.nuxt',`

so you can use the plogins in dev