# Nuxt SSR firebase functions returns 504 timeout

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I'm trying to implement Nuxt with SSR in Firebase hosting (using Firebase functions), but after my function is triggered I keep getting an '504 timed out waiting for function to respond'.

My Firebase function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { Nuxt } = require("nuxt");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const config = {
    dev: false,
    buidlDir: 'src',
    build: {
        publicPath: '/'
    }
};

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

function handleRequest(req, res){
    console.log('handling request');
    //res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200')
    nuxt.renderRoute('/')
    .then(result => {
        console.log('result: ' + result.html);
        res.send(result.html);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        res.send(e);
        console.log(e);
    })
}
app.get('*', handleRequest);
exports.ssrApp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I also tried with:

```
function handleRequest(req, res) {
    console.log("log3");
    res.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      nuxt.render(req, res, promise => {
        promise.then(resolve).catch(reject);
      });
    });
  }
```

I also have node vs8 as default for my functions because I read that that could give problems. :

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
```

But with the same result. My function is being triggered but it always times out, btw: I have this problem serving locally and when trying to deploy to Firebase itself.

Let me know if you need more information/code to try to help and see what the problem could be.

Comment: anyone knows this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to find out what caused it, [use debug option](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2047#h5o-13).

Second, if you face the timeout error, check the path is valid.
If you success build Nuxt and `nuxt.render`, the error is processed by Nuxt, and Nuxt show [this error page](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/b83b5675043ebdfec3398bd83fd27dfe77cdd620/packages/vue-app/template/views/error.html).
In other words, if you don't see Nuxt error page, the cause may be not related with Nuxt.

I also stuck 4 hours due to timeout error, and I finally found out the cause was the contents of `publicPath`.

Please check these 2 things.

1. `buidlDir` is valid ?

The path of `buildDir` is valid ? You should check `.nuxt` folder is deployed to your cloud functions successfully.

2. `publicPath` contents is uploaded successfully?

The builded contents in `.nuxt/dist` must be uploaded to Firebase Hosting. You should check it manually.
Type URL to address bar ex) https://test.firebaseapp.com/path/to/file.js

Finally, I post a URL of 
[my sample project, using Nuxt and Firebase](https://github.com/Mizumaki/Nuxt_SSR_TypeScript_Firebase_Workbox_example).

I also stucked like you and it made me rally tired. I'm really happy if this answer helps someone like me.

PS: When you build Nuxt in `functions` folder, `nuxt start` is failed. Be careful. In my project, I build it in root, and when deploy, I copied it.
[Nuxt SSR with Firebase Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839593/nuxt-ssr-with-firebase-integration)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem because **Nuxt is not ready** yet (`promise` is undefined)

So you can try to add `nuxt.ready()` after `new Nuxt()`

**Example:**

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt');
const config = {
  dev: false
  // Your config
};
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);
const app = express();

nuxt.ready(); // <---------- Add this!

async function handleRequest(req, res) {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=1, s-maxage=1');
  await nuxt.render(req, res);
}

app.get('*', handleRequest);
app.use(handleRequest);

exports.ssrApp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Ref: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js#using-nuxtjs-programmatically